# php doesn't execute query

Tags: php, mysql, execute

I've two mysql tables, here is sql for them =>

I'm making dynamic menu with its sub menu . SO I've the situation that want to execute such a query

```
DELETE FROM artinfo WHERE descName=(SELECT for_sub_url FROM menu WHERE menu_id=" . $_POST['main_menu_titles'] . ")
```

where **$_POST['main_menu_titles']** exists and is menu_id. I'm not writing php code too , because it works just fine and remarkable is that , this query executes when I am trying to execute it from mysql shell (of course using directly number of menu_id instead of $_POST['m_num'])

Any ideas whats going on, how to execute it from php script ? thanks :)

**UPDATE**

here is php script

```
if ($connection->query("DELETE FROM artinfo WHERE descName=(SELECT for_sub_url FROM menu WHERE menu_id=" . $_POST['main_menu_titles'] . ")") && $connection->query("DELETE FROM artinfo WHERE descName IS NULL AND cat_id=" . $_POST['main_menu_titles'] . "")){
                            $edit_res_fine = "DELETED";
                        }
```

Comment: Can you show the PHP code that attempts to run the query?

Comment: Nice [SQL injection vulnerability](http://bobby-tables.com). Enjoy having your server pwn3d. Does that subquery return a single row? If it's multiple, you'll have to change the outer query to be `WHERE descName IN (...)` instead.

Comment: What is the MySQL error that's being thrown?

Comment: In some circumstances table name 'artInfo' is not the same as 'artinfo' - it depends from OS and mysql configuration. Maybe this is your error

Comment: in this situation it doesn't matter `artInfo` is written or `artinfo`, also have tried those cases

Comment: What does the MySQL error say?

Comment: nothing , when I am writing this query directly in mysql shell and of course using menu_id instead of $_POST it executes fine , but in php script it doesn't , and how I mentioned $_POST sending value

Comment: var_dump( $_POST['m_num'] ); What do you get?

Comment: I am getting this `string(1) "1"`

Comment: of course number is changeable , depends on situation

Comment: This example is completely **reckless** and should **never** go into production. If you're not using placeholders and proper SQL escaping, stop what you're doing now and learn how to use them properly. These are not optional. [SQL Escaping for PHP](http://bobby-tables.com/php) What you're doing is the equivalent of a hospital re-using rusty needles for administering medication.

Comment: in this situation does it matter that the menu_id column has the integer type and the $_POST which is sending value in menu_id has string type ?

Answer (score 0):

If you say the query works just fine without $_POST, I would think the code in question is located in the form you submit to acquire $_POST['main_menu_titles']. To test the correct value is being sent, try echoing the value of $_POST['main_menu_titles'] right before the query.

Comment: right advice , but in php code which I've written , I mean second query which is written executes fine , that proves that `$_POST` is sending value :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
$query = "DELETE FROM artinfo WHERE descName = (SELECT for_sub_url FROM menu 
WHERE menu_id = '" . $_POST['m_num'] . "')";
```

Comment: I've tried already , Also have tried `"DELETE FROM artinfo WHERE descName = '(SELECT for_sub_url FROM menu 
WHERE menu_id = '" . $_POST['m_num'] . "')'"`

Comment: did you try distinct? 
`"DELETE FROM artinfo WHERE descName = '(SELECT DISTINCT for_sub_url FROM menu WHERE menu_id = '" . $_POST['m_num'] . "')'"`